# How do I use reCAPTCHA Ver 2 with Java?

Tags: java, recaptcha

I am trying to implement reCAPTCHA ver 2 in my Java web application. To verify the user's response I need to get the value of `g-recaptcha-response` which reCAPTCHA posts to my server, according to the tutorials [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify). But Java does not allow variable names with hyphens in them. How do I get this value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a variable called `g-recaptcha-response`.  That is the name of a parameter in an HTTP POST request.  You simply retrieve the parameter value from the request, and store it in a Java variable ... whose name is whatever you want it to be.

```
 String str = request.getParameter("g-recaptcha-response");
```

Here are the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) for the `ServletRequest` class.